# Jackson ObjectMapper.readValue()

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am reading a List of integers using Jackson as follows:

```
List<Integer> businessIds = mapper.readValue(strBusinessIDArrayJSON, new TypeReference<List<Integer>>(){});
```

The returned list contains a list of businesses displayed in a Grid on my UI. I have the following questions:

1. Will the returned list maintain Sequence. In my code, I am populating a variable called businessDisplayPosition with the index of the list. Is this how its done?
2. Is there a faster way to parse my JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, of course. Otherwise, an array and a list wouldn't be an array and a list anymore. Test it, and see by yourself.
2. there's probably a faster way, but it will probably not be as convenient, and the way you're doing it is probably fast enough. Unless you have millions and millions of IDs in your array, I doubt the user would notice any difference between this solution and a faster one. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Don't try to optimize something that doesn't need to be.